# WPF TreeView with child nodes under distinct categories

Tags: c#, wpf

Given the following class `Foo`

```
class Foo {
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Given a `List<Foo>` where `Property1` is a category, so multiple instances of Foo in the collection have the same value for `Property1`. `Property2` is unique in this case, but that is not relevant.

I want to show the collection of Foo in a TreeView in `WPF`, where for every `Distinct` `Property1` it shows a node (with the value of `Property1` as the header). And as child items of that node it should have all the instances of Foo with that `Property1`, and it should have `Property2` as the header.

So far I have tried the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` approach (would prefer) and the code behind, but neither seem to have the result I want. Here is the code behind I tried:

```
private void ReloadTree() {
    var uniqueProperty1 = foos
        .Select(f => f.Property1)
        .Distinct();

    var result = new List<TreeViewItem>();
    
    foreach (var prop1 in uniqueProperty1) {
        var item = new TreeViewItem();
        item.Header = name;
        item.IsExpanded = false;
    
        var attributes = new List<Foo>();

        foreach (var foo in attributes) {
            var subItem = new TreeViewItem();
            subItem.Header = foo.Property2;

            item.Items.Add(subItem);
        }

        bindingsTree.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Where `foos` is the collection of `Foo`, and `bindingsTree` is the `TreeView`. Any help would be really appreciated!

#### Edit

To clarify given the following list of foos:

```
var list = new List<Foo>()
{
    new Foo() { Property1 = "category1", Property2 = "A" },
    new Foo() { Property1 = "category1", Property2 = "B" },
    new Foo() { Property1 = "category2", Property2 = "C" },
    new Foo() { Property1 = "category2", Property2 = "D" },
};
```

The result should look like this:

```
+category1
    - A
    - B
+category2
    - C
    - D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an hierarchical model type:

```
class FooViewModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FooViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

...and group `foos` by `Property1`:

```
private void ReloadTree()
{
    var categories = foos
        .GroupBy(x => x.Property1)
        .Select(x => new FooViewModel { Category = x.Key, Children = x.Select(y => new FooViewModel() { Category = y.Property2 }).ToArray() })
        .ToArray();

    bindingsTree.ItemsSource = categories;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView x:Name="bindingsTree">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I was overthinking this-_-